# Android outOfMemory error recycling does not work

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I have 10 small pictures on the main screen and when i click these images i can see as big picture
and  at this screen i have a button to set as wallpaper.

The problem is that when i click some difference pictures i have outOfMemoryError , i can't fix this error. i tried some solution but i think my problem is difference little bit.

```
public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

        Button button1;

      @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

           button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

            Intent i = getIntent();
     final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");


        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);




            if(position==0)
            {

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_0);




                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager 
                        = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                        try {


                            myWallpaperManager.setResource(R.drawable.image_0);

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getBaseContext(),
                                    "Wallpaper has been updated",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });


                }
```

i have 10 position like this.My images come from drawable folder.

i have tried this solution but i can't fix it.i don't know where i use it.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable());


            if (null != bitmapDrawable && bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {

                bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();    } 
                bitmapDrawable = null;
```

Here is the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {


                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);

            }
});
}

    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();
        // retrieve String drawable array
        TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
        for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }

        return imageItems;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main screen where you display 10 small pictures, I guess you use code like this:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(R.drawable.image0);
```

Even if your ImageViews show on small areas of screen, the Drawables are still decoded as full size instead of scaling to fit the ImageView's size. You should decode those Drawables into bitmaps with appropriate size before set to those ImageViews.
You can take a look at this topic to see how to do that http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: the solutions on the website. Which one shoud i use and where ?

Comment: As I said those code should be modified: "for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                    imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
        }" _________ You should follow the guide in the link. First, only decode bound to get the size of the images, then calculate the sample size, and use that sample size to decode the scaled down images for memory efficient. There is also sample project in the link.